# Operation referenced in sudoers still fails on kill command

Tags: sudo, kill

I what to be able to restart ConnMan from within Node-RED.
That service runs with its own user `nodered`.

When I SSH into the device as the `nodered` user and type

```
nodered@pi:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/connman restart
```

that works.

However, when I call `visudo` and add the following line:

```
nodered ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/connman restart
```

it gives me the following error when executing the command:

```
nodered@pi:~$ /etc/init.d/connman restart
Restarting Connection Manager
/etc/init.d/connman: line 47: kill: (28874) - Operation not permitted
```

The line that fails in `/etc/init.d/connman` is:

```
do_stop() {
        # kill the script monitoring execution
        if [ "X${pid=$(pidof -x /usr/sbin/connmand-watch.sh)}" != "X" ]; then
                kill $pid 
        fi

        start-stop-daemon --stop --name connmand --quiet
}
```

I don't want to add `kill` explicitly to the `sudoers` file for that user because I fear it could be misused for any `kill` commands besides the intended use. Any way I can solve this?

Comment: Note that in the command that fails, you didn't call sudo at all, so you are not able to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

If the service and its watcher both run as user `nodered` and you log in as the same user, then you don't need `sudo` at all: the owner of the process will always have permission to kill it, even with `kill -9` if necessary.

This `sudoers` line:

```
nodered ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/connman restart
```

grants the `nodered` user the ability to run the command `/etc/init.d/connman restart` as root. If the script or the service itself won't ensure the service and its watcher both start as the `nodered` user, running this script with `sudo` may have the unintended side effect of restarting the service and/or the `connmand-watch.sh` script as root-owned processes. Be careful.

With `kill -0`, you can test whether or not you can kill a process, without really sending any signal. You could do something like this in the beginning of your `/etc/init.d/connman` script:

```
if [ $(whoami) != "root" ]; then
    watcherpid=$(pidof -x /usr/sbin/connmand-watch.sh)
    if [ "" != "$watcherpid" ] && ! kill -0 "$watcherpid" 2>/dev/null; then
        # Watcher exists but cannot be signaled so it runs as some other user.
        # Attempt to re-execute this script with root powers.
        exec sudo /etc/init.d/connman "$@"
        # If we reach this line, we could not exec sudo. That's bad.
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

With `exec sudo /etc/init.d/connman "$@"`, the script will re-run itself via sudo. Because of `exec`, the execution of the regular non-privileged copy of the script will end right there, and the `sudo`ed version will replace it, using the same command line parameters as the original invocation.

If the watcher process cannot be found, or the script is run already as root, this test will fall through without doing anything.

Note: if the script tries to re-run itself with `sudo` and the attempt fails, the script will stop without doing anything.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried as you suggested and inserted your code block. But it gives the following output:

`nodered@pi:~$ /etc/init.d/connman restart
/etc/init.d/connman: line 13: kill: (1527) - Operation not permitted
Restarting Connection Manager
/etc/init.d/connman: line 64: start-stop-daemon: command not found`

Line 64 is at the end of this block:
`do_stop() {
        # kill the script monitoring execution
        if [ "X${pid=$(pidof -x /usr/sbin/connmand-watch.sh)}" != "X" ]; then
                kill $pid
        fi

        start-stop-daemon --stop --name connmand --quiet
}`

Comment: Oops, I forgot that the `kill -0` test needs a `2>/dev/null` to silence the error message. And the `command not found` should be fixed by specifying`start-stop-daemon` using a full path, i.e. `/usr/sbin/start-stop-daemon`.